# Finding general forms of sums in Mathematica

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation

A general form can be obtained for some sums with binomial coefficients. 
**Mathematica** is able to find these general forms for some of the simplest sums. For others the output contains for instance some ugly `DifferenceRoot`.  My question is how to help Mathematica find general forms of more complicated sums.

Examples

- This equation $\sum_k\binom{2k}{k}\binom{4n-2k}{2n-k}=2^{4n}$ Mathematica is able to handle.
- However, one can rewrite the above equation to: $\sum_{k=-n}^{k=n}\binom{2n+2k}{n+k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}=2^{4n}$. This one produces the output with the mentioned `DifferenceRoot`.
- An obvious trick working for some simpler sums is `FullSimplify`. The example is $\sum_{k=0}^g \binom{4g+2}{g}=2^{4g}$.

What are more sophisticated tricks and techniques or how to handle the output to make it *eatable*?

Comment: Mathematica is not a magic box that'll spit out a solution to any problem..With Maple I have: $\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \binom{2 n+2 k}{n+k} \binom{2 n-2 k}{n-k}=\frac{16^n}{2}+\frac{\binom{2 n}{n}^2}{2}$ and it's a correct answer.

Comment: "some ugly `DifferenceRoot`" - at the very least, it tells you the recurrence satisfied by your expression; at most, you can use `FunctionExpand[]` on it to find a more conventional expression. Characterizing it as "ugly" is a little unfair.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. @Mariusz: I made a small correction. I meant $k$ to go through also negative values (but of course for $|k|>n the sum elements are zero); I added sum limits. 
I will try `FunctionExpand`.

Comment: `FunctionExpand[DifferenceRoot`... returns the same `DifferenceRoot...`. I called `DifferenceRoot` ugly because one can [find](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/91264) opinions as <<*(...) returns a `DifferenceRoot` expression - i.e., it can't be given in "closed form". Mathematica is then unable to compute the commented out `Sum`.*>>

I understand Mathematica is not a magic box. But I assume there may be ways of giving Mathematica some hints (I saw Q&A where changing Method helped). Finding out hints needed to solve known problems, may help solve more complex ones.